# Consuming integer value returned by Win32 DLL in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dll

I'm trying to use Powershell to receive the response from a DLL.

The DLL is written in x86 assembly language (not .NET) and expects 2 input parameters, both strings (an IPv4 address and a Date).

I wrote the DLL, so there is no ambiguity that it's returning the wrong value as it has previously been extensively used by being called from a native Win32 application.

The return value is an unsigned integer (This is returned in the CPU register EAX as either 100 - The IP address was not found, or 200 The IP address was found).

For the non-assembly language programmers, EAX is where values are usually returned, for example, a Yes No message box, would return the values for Yes or No within EAX.

A little more background, another of the functions works fine, it's the same input parameters, however, in this instance, a pointer to a string is returned.

It's definitely something to do with the int that is returned being confused with a pointer as I see this message:

```
The pointer passed in as a String must not be in the bottom 64K of the process's address space.
```

Here is the relevant code sections:

```
#IPv42Proxy returns either 100 or 200 as an int
$S_IPv42Proxy = @'
[DllImport(@"D:\lp2\iplookup.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern string IPv42Proxy(string ipv4, string date);
'@;
```

```
$t5 = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $S_IPv42Proxy -Name v4Proxy -Namespace IPLookup -PassThru;
```

And the code where the error is generated:

```
$retval2 = $t5::IPv42Proxy($src_ip, $actual_date)
```

I understand it is most likely to do with casting as everything seems to be relating so strings, but not being a HLL programmer, really struggle with this.

The code samples above were found online and modified to suit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may have already done this, but type `Get-Help Add-Type -Examples` into powershell. The first example explains how this is supposed to be used. The fifth example looks more like what you are trying to do though.

Comment: Also, it is probably returning a string since that is what you are telling it to do here `public static extern string IPv42Proxy(string ipv4, string date);`

Comment: try using this instead `public static extern uint16 IPv42Proxy(string ipv4, string date);`

Comment: I could be completely off base though. I am not an assembly language programmer.

Comment: As a follow up to this, it now seems to work using the code samples that I posted earlier, I exited the Powershell ISE, went back in and it works. This is something to consdier when code does not work!

Comment: Very true. Sometimes powershell gets stuck and needs to be restarted :)